# Make an event handler seamless?

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I have written an event handler under `Excel online add-in`. It is activated by a button `activate`, then when a user clicks on another cell or range, the address will be written on a text area `myTextArea`. The whole thing works.

However, once a new cell is selected, a green loading symbol is shown near the focus; `WORKING...` is shown on the bottom of Excel; it takes almost `0.5 second`.

I am just surprised that it takes time for such a simple action. Does anyone know if it is possible to make this event hander faster? Otherwise, is there any other mean than event handling to make this seamless?

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    Office.initialize = function(reason) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            app.initialize();            
            $('#activate').click(addSelectionChangedEventHandler);
        });
    }
    ;

    function addSelectionChangedEventHandler() {
        Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged, MyHandler);
    }

    function MyHandler(eventArgs) {
        doStuffWithNewSelection();
    }

    function doStuffWithNewSelection() {
        Excel.run(function(ctx) {
            var selectedRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
            selectedRange.load(["address"]);
            return ctx.sync().then(function() {
                write(selectedRange.address)
            })
        }).then(function() {
            console.log("done");
        }).catch(function(error) {
           ...
        });
    }    

    function write(message) {
       document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = message;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is network lag.  The selection changed event -- once registered -- originates on the server, and triggers the code if Office.js that fires your event handler.  Your event handler, in turn, creates a local request for getting the selection Range object and its address, sends it over to the server as part of `ctx.sync()`, and then waits to hear back from the server before firing the `.then`.

There's not anything you can do to optimize this flow -- you will pay a pretty high per-transaction cost on Excel Online, and event handlers only add one extra step to that cost.  On the other hand, the good news is that the `Excel.run/ctx`-based model does allow you to batch multiple requests into one, drastically reducing the number of roundtrips that would otherwise be required.  That is, fetching the values of 10 different ranges is almost identical in speed to fetching just one; whereas it would be 10 times more expensive if each call were made individually.

Hope this helps!

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT